# Through what ways could audiences watch film back in the day

Tags: word-usage, word-choice, sentence-construction, british-english

does this sound right to ur ears ?

**Through what ways could audiences watch film back in the day?**

if not, how would you express the same idea ?

Many thanks

Comment: *How did audiences watch films {time-phrase}?*.  It's not clear what you mean by "back in the day".  Before internet streaming?  Before DVD? Before VCR? Before drive-in movie theaters?

Comment: I just want to emphasise  how many ways were there in the past, back in the day is just what i learned from british people.   how should i construct the sentence then ? if i want to emphasise how many ways ?

Comment: Are you talking about the venues or about the distribution media? They're not completely separable, I realize.

Answer (score 1):

The phrase "back in the day" is an extremely informal phrase, and the more formal "Through what ways could" is quite jarring when the two are combined. Worse, without context "back in the day" could mean 5 years ago or 20 or 80 years ago, depending on the speaker. Obviously, people watched film 5 years ago just as they do now. 80 years ago they watched film exclusively in theaters. Until "back in the day" is better-defined the idea behind the question is not readily formulated.

That said, you could ask something like "Back in the day, how could audiences watch films?"

Comment: I see the point, but i want to emphasise how many ways were there in the past, how should i construct the sentence then ?

Comment: @SampsonGao - If you want to emphasize that there were many ways in the past, you should not ask a question, but rather make a statement.